# select statement to carry over closing balance to the following

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I am trying to select the closing balance of the previous month and using it as the opening balance of the next month but I seem not to get the right result.

I have used this code to select other columns and get the balance:

```
SELECT Year1,StockNumber,InventoryName,Month1, 
       SUM(ABS(RECEIVE_FROM_PO)) AS RPO,SUM(ABS(RECEIVE_XFER))AS XEFR, 
       SUM(ABS(RECEIVE_ADJ)) as RDJ,SUM(ABS(RETURN1)) AS RET, 
       SUM(ABS(TRANSFER)) as TSFR,SUM(ABS(ISSUE)) as ISS, SUM(ABS(PT_ISSUE))as PISS, 
       SUM(ABS(ADJUSTMENT)) as ADJ,  
       (Sum(ABS(RECEIVE_FROM_PO + RECEIVE_XFER + RECEIVE_ADJ + RETURN1)) - Sum(ABS(TRANSFER+ISSUE+PT_ISSUE+ADJUSTMENT))) as Balance 
FROM dbo.Sheet2$
where Year1 ='' and InventoryName ='' and StockNumber =''
GROUP BY Year1,InventoryName,StockNumber,Month1,balance
```

With this code I am able to get the balance and now I want to use that balance as opening balance for the following month. How is the SQL script and can it be done using Crystal Reports?

Answer (score 0):

Crystal report has the capability of doing the group function like sum, min, max etc.. It has all the rich functionality.. If you fail on creating the query, take the table Sheet2$ in the crystal report, then create the summary field for each sum in your query.